# Busca Binária Recursiva não encontra o elemento na ultima posição do vetor

Tags: java, array, busca-binária

Fiz um código de busca binária recursiva em Java. Ele encontra as posições corretamente, exceto quando o elemento buscado ocupa a última posição do vetor. Não sei como corrigir isso.

```
public static int binarySearchRecursivo(int array[],int x) {
        return BinarySearchRec(array, x, 0, array.length-1);
        }
    
        public static int BinarySearchRec(int array[], int x, int inicio, int fim) {
         int meio = (inicio+fim)/2;
         if (inicio <= fim) {
             
         if (array[meio]==x) {
             return meio;
         }
         if (array[meio]<x) {
             return BinarySearchRec(array, x, meio+1, fim);
         }
         else {
             return BinarySearchRec(array, x, inicio, meio-1);
         }
         }
         return -1;
        }
    
    // Driver method to test above
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        int arr[] = {2,3,5,6,7,9,12,33,66,55};
        int x = 55;
        int result = binarySearchRecursivo(arr,x);
        if (result ==-1)
            System.out.println("Elemento não está presente");
        else
            System.out.println("Elemento encontrado na posição " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Em uma [busca binária](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), um dos pré-requisitos é que todos os elementos estejam em ordem, caso contrário **não** há garantia nenhuma que funcionará.

No seu caso, o array não está ordenado, pois o penúltimo elemento (66) é maior que o último (55).

Se o array estiver ordenado, aí funciona:

```
// trocando o 55 e 66 de posição, agora o array está ordenado
int arr[] = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 33, 55, 66 };
int x = 66;
// restante do código igual, 66 é encontrado
```